# How to bind combox with 2 different tables in c# windows form

Tags: c#, sql, combobox

So basically i want customer names in combox which i get using 2 tables.
Below table name is SaleOrders, and i am getting CustomerId from this table

[image]

and on behalf of those CustomerId i am fetching Customer names from the below table named, "Customers".

[image]

So, my target is to get the SaleOrderId from SaleOrders according to selected Customer name from combox.

here is the method where i get customer names and load it into combox named, customerid_cb.

```
private void GetCustomerId()
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("select Name from Customers  inner join SaleOrders 
                              SaleOrders.CustomerId=Customers.CustomerId where Status=3", con);
        read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (read.Read())
        {
            customerid_cb.Items.Add(read.GetValue(0).ToString());
        }
    }
```

and here is the method where i get SaleOrderId and load it into combox named saleorderid_cb.

```
 private void GetSaleOrderId()
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("select SaleOrderId from SaleOrders s , Customers c where Status=3 and  
                c.CustomerId='" + customerid_cb.Text + "'" + " and c.CustomerId=s.CustomerId", con);
        read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (read.Read())
        {
            saleorderid_cb.Items.Add(read.GetValue(0).ToString());
        }
        con.Close();
       }
```

**PROBLEM:**

So, the problem i am facing is CustomerId 71 and 75 have same names, so when i select first "df" from combox (customerid_cb) it display 67 and 68 SaleOrderId on saleorderid_cb, and i want to show only 67 SaleOrderId as CustomerId 75 have only 67 SaleOrderId, same for 71 CustomerId.
The solution which i realize is to bind the customeid_cb with 2 tables SaleOrders and Customers, but i didnt get any solution to do this.

I hope my question is clear to you.If anyone know how to fix this, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole reason why we have unique IDs is to allow things like names to be the same and still be able to tell people apart

If we select the names *and* the IDs, then we can carry on telling people apart:

```
private void FillCustomers() //name methods appropriately; this method is void - it didn't "Get" anything
{
    
    using(da = new SqlDataAdapter("select DISTINCT c.Name, c.Id 
      from Customers c 
      inner join SaleOrders s ON s.CustomerId = c.CustomerId 
      where s.Status=3", con);
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        customerid_cb.DisplayMember = "Name";
        customerid_cb.ValueMember = "Id";
        customerid_cb.DataSource = dt;
    }
}
```

Then when we want to look something up we can do it by their Id:

```
private void FillSaleOrders() 
{
    using(da = new SqlDataAdapter("select SaleOrderId from SaleOrders
       where Status = 3 AND CustomerId=@custId", con); //NEVER ever concatenate values into an SQL string - number one way of getting hacked. See http://bobby-tables.com
    {
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@custid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = customerid_cb.SelectedValue; //use the ID of the customer for the search param not their name
        var dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        saleorderid_cb.DisplayMember = "SaleOrderId"; //you'd be better off showing something else
        saleorderid_cb.ValueMember = "SaleOrderId";
        saleorderid_cb.DataSource = dt;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir!! It works. and thank you for giving advises!!. God Bless you.